# Menu Css for single item color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

This is my menu : http://goo.gl/IeXLW6
I would like red for only item "Submit Event" in menu. How it possibile?

Comment: Add a special class just for that ID?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All menu's have different id in list tag. You can use that.

```
#menu-item-428 a {
    color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

Comment: !important isn't needed and this answer already exists

Comment: !important is needed here, You should check his site first.

Comment: I have checked his site, and it isn't needed

Comment: Without !important, Its not working. Please check again.

Comment: Seriously, it is not needed

Comment: Thanks for all, work only with important tag.

Answer (score -1):

Since anchor tag is wrapped inside li tag which is having ID as **#menu-item-428**.

You can use its ID to apply css styling to anchor tag (descendant selector):

CSS :

```
#menu-item-428 a {
    color: red;
}
```

For more info. on applying CSS styling using combination of elements, check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp).